# Cross browser support for CSS Masking

Tags: html, css, svg, linear-gradients

I would like to achieve color palette gradients using **CSS**(**SVG** can be used in case for cross-browser compatibility). Gradients can be achieved using CSS linear gradient in all browsers and using **filter** for IE 9 and below.

[image: gradient]

To achieve the above gradient, I have to use masking. But please let me know if this can be achieved without using masking.

Masking using linear gradient in CSS is working fine in **Safari** and **Chrome** but not in **IE** and **Mozilla**.

To support masking in **Mozilla**, I have used SVG mask element, but it is not scaling for all sizes. I have to give exact viewport dimension (0, 0, 256, 256) to make it work for Gradient of dimension(256 X 256). How can I achieve this for all sizes?  Or can I achieve this only using CSS as if in Chrome and Safari? Or any other better way?

I would like to achieve the same in IE but, either of these methods is not supported in IE. I would like to know if there are any better ways to handle these.

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/brindhaa10/tL1nx8uq/4/

```css
 .picker{
            width:128px;
            height:128px;
            position: relative;
        }

.picker > *{
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        top:0px;
}

.red1{
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(red), to(magenta));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red, magenta);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red, magenta);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, red, magenta);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, red, magenta);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, magenta);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1,startColorstr='red', endColorstr='magenta');/*For IE7-8-9*/
    }
    .red2{
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(black), to(blue));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black, blue);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, black, blue);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, black, blue);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, black, blue);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, blue);

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='black', endColorstr='blue');/*For IE7-8-9*/    
         /* LINEAR GRADIENT - SUPPORTED ONLY IN CHROME AND SAFARI*/
        -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, black 100%);
        mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, black 100%);
        -moz-mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, black 100%);

        /*SVG AS MASK --- SUPPORT FOR MOZILLA*/
        mask:url(#mask2);

    }
```

```html
<svg width="0px" height="0px" viewport='0 0 128 128'>
<defs>
<mask id="mask2">
    <linearGradient id="maskGrad" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ffffff"> </stop>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#000000"> </stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#maskGrad)"></rect>
</mask>
</defs>
</svg>
<div class='picker'>
   <div class='red1'></div>
   <div class='red2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe CSS masking will be available in Firefox 53. Also it's viewBox not viewport as an attribute.

Comment: Check the available browser support for CSS mask [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask)